# PHP Script to handle end of year calculation automatically?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that calls an API and then downloads/saves the data to a CSV.

- Using the following filter, it works perfectly for months 1 thru 11
- but fails for month 12 because the year changes.

How would I adjust this to make it work for all months?

```
$cYmPlus1 = "year(t1.inv_date) = " . date('Y') . " and month(t1.inv_date) = " . (date('m')+1);
```

Comment: Could you not just check `if (date('m') == 12) { ++$year; }` (of course setting `$year = date('Y')` before and using `$year` in the interpolation instead)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 1 month to the current date, then extract the year and month from that, rather than adding to month. You also don't need to use PHP date functions, you can do it entirely in MySQL.

```
YEAR(t1.inv_date) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND
MONTH(t1.inv_date) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Comment: Barmar, thanks for the post.. I'll give it a try!

Will your idea work since I'm doing this using: curl_setopt($http_resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('companyId'=>'901', 'QRTQueryId'=>'9105','QRTFilter'=>$cYmPlus1, 'webServiceKey'=>'1234'));

Comment: If the filter is being put into the `WHERE` clause of a MySQL query it should work fine.

Comment: Unless the client and server are in different timezones. There could be a problem then if you run it within a few hours of the end of the year.

Comment: Barmar, looks like your code worked for month 12.. will see how it does in Jan... thanks!